# Ktor stops responding when using JWTs

Tags: ktor

We are using ktor 2.1.0 version and have configured multiple JWK providers.
Our application have 3 endpoints, one is health check without authorization.

When one of the JWK providers starts responding very slow, our application endpoints stops responding (event that without authorization health check) and waits while first request for the slow JWK provider will be finished.

It's look like what all Ktor stops responding during bearer token validation.

Can it be some configuration issue? Or it is a bug in Ktor?

We upgraded jwks-rsa to the 0.21.2 version. This one gives us ability to set the timeouts, but with these timeouts we cover the problem, but not solving.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean by very slow responding?

Comment: I was mean that response was retrieved after 30 seconds or event timeout occurs after more than 60 seconds

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you please share a code snippet for your server?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: yes, solved. Problem was with the configuration of the JWK providers and proxy settings.